# how to handle or remove 'Find records' and 'Reload Grid' options from jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

There are 2 icons present on footer of my jqgrid where pager appeares. Tooltip of those icons say 'Find records' and 'Reload Grid'. Either tell me way to handle these functions of jqgrid or tell me how to remove these icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit the jqGrid navigator options search and refresh ( [jqGgrid wiki:navigator](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator))

```
jQuery("#grid_id").navGrid('#gridpager',{search:false, refresh:false});
```